# Step Function definition in Terraform (Yaml)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-step-functions

I have already implemented SFn in Terraform (JSON) file:

```
data "template_file" "sfn-definition" {
  template = file("step-function-definition.json")
}

resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine" {
   name = "integration-step-function"
   role_arn = aws_iam_role.step_function_role.arn
   definition = data.template_file.sfn-definition.rendered
}
```

It's working fine, but instead of JSON, I would like to use YAML definition.
I created the same SFn definition in YAML. I did it in AWS Toolkit (VS Code) and the graph is rendered correctly. I change JSON file to YAML:

```
template = file("step-function-definition.yaml")
```

And unfortunately it not works:

```
08:58:39  Error: Error creating Step Function State Machine: InvalidDefinition: 
Invalid State Machine Definition: 'INVALID_JSON_DESCRIPTION: 
Unrecognized token 'StartAt': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

I suppose that `definition` in `aws_sfn_state_machine` expect JSON file, but is there any option to define SFn in YAML and use Terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Amazon States Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html) is **JSON-based**. So you have to convert your yaml to json first. You can try the following:

```
template = jsonencode(yamldecode(file("step-function-definition.yaml")))
```